# My session ends after trying to open settings

Tags: settings

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and tried open settings (either from top right corner or in the main panel) and screen just goes black, and the session is closed so I have to re-enter my user, and it happens again and again. Any solution for this? Thanks :)

Comment: After trying that's and it still did not fix the problem, update to a more recent version 20.0 or 22.4 might do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I had to purge gnome-control-center from terminal and reinstall it

- sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
- sudo apt autoremove
- sudo apt install gnome-control-center